# Execution order of element properties in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

Is there a way to execute attached behavior last, after initialization of list properties in following example

```
<LinearGradientBrush local:FreezeBehavior.IsFrozen="True">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

It can be done like this

```
<GradientStopCollection x:Key="SomeKey">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
</GradientStopCollection>

<LinearGradientBrush GradientStops="{StaticResource SomeKey}" local:FreezeBehavior.IsFrozen="True"/>
```

But it will require to create dozens of unnecessary `ResourceDictionary` entries.

P.S.: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24861598/1997232) (in case someone see this as duplicate, then vote close it instead of this one, here I already know the problem and it's more clearly described).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess execution flow is based on XAML Parser, and in parse properties as they appear. So you can try to reorder declarations of properties. Something like this:

```
<LinearGradientBrush>
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
    <local:FreezeBehavior.IsFrozen>True</local:FreezeBehavior.IsFrozen>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

<strike>May be you'll have to use `<sys:Bool>True</sys:Bool>` as value of `FreezeBehavior.IsFrozen`</strike>